# What is wrong with my short URL rewrite code?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite a URL from mysite.com/123 to mysite.com/redirect.php?referral=123

Currently, my .htaccess file is using the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ redirect.php?referral=$1AddHandler php-files .php
```

I'm positive it was working before, but now I get a 500 error code.

Comment: Why is `AddHandler` on a separate line?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see it on a separate line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant why is it *not* on a separate line. It should be.

Comment: Do you mean just add a "return" between "=" and "$"? I just tried that and it still gives me a 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two lines of your file appear to have been concatenated. Change it to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ redirect.php?referral=$1
AddHandler php-files .php
```

Comment: Now it randomly changed from trying to download a file to "this file isn't on the server" (basically the same result I got when commenting out the htaccess).

Comment: It's working now. I think it just took a while to get the changes.I also cleared my browser cache. Thank you for your help.